# SonarQube API for getting critical security vulnerabilities

Tags: sonarqube

Is there a SonarQube API available that will give me the security vulnerabilities and bugs of specific criticality (Ex: Blocker).

Comment: I have tried the below APIs, but it does not give me the details Iam looking for...

Comment: api/measures/component and  api/measures/search_history

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [GET api/issues/search](https://sonarcloud.io/web_api/api/issues/search) with `severities` parameter.

> Search for issues.
>
> At most one of the following parameters can be provided at the same time: componentKeys and componentUuids.
>   Requires the 'Browse' permission on the specified project(s).
>
> `severities` optional
>
> Comma-separated list of severities
>
> Possible values
>
> - INFO
> - MINOR
> - MAJOR
> - CRITICAL
> - BLOCKER
>
> Example value: **BLOCKER,CRITICAL**

**UPDATE**

In order to retrieve only the newer issues, you could use:

> `sinceLeakPeriod`
>
> To retrieve issues created since the leak period.
>   If this parameter is set to a truthy value, createdAfter must not be set and one component id or key must be provided.
>
> Possible values
>
> - true
> - false
> - yes
> - no
>
> Default value: **false**

or

> `createdAfter`
>
> To retrieve issues created after the given date (inclusive).
>   Either a date (server timezone) or datetime can be provided.
>   If this parameter is set, createdSince must not be set
>
> Example value: **2017-10-19** or **2017-10-19T13:00:00+0200**

or even

> `createdInLast`
>
> To retrieve issues created during a time span before the current time (exclusive). Accepted units are 'y' for year, 'm' for month, 'w' for week and 'd' for day. If this parameter is set, createdAfter must not be set
>
> Example value: **1m2w** (1 month 2 weeks)

Just be aware that these parameters are mutually exclusive, and `sinceLeakPeriod` forces you to specify one component. See the [API documentation](https://sonarcloud.io/web_api/api/issues/search) for more details and examples.